# Is it posible to now show loading when load addThis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

If the script tag is after addthis div. It slow down loading of the page, I don't care that it slow down, but I would like to now show that the page is sill loading (google chrome show load favicon). I removed the script tag and put it to $(funcion) in my external file where all my jQuery code is. But when script is loaded it still show loading favicon.

```
var src = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=boobaloo';
$.getScript(src);
```

I also try to use

```
$('<script/>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
```

Is it posible to load addthis buttons and don't show that page is still loading? Can someone  explain why it show that the page is loading?

Comment: because the browser is making a request, it will show when you do ajax calls, or in your case a script loading, unfortunately it's nothing you can do about it...

Comment: @Val ajax call are not show up, the same as adding new dynamic image to the page. If ajax call will show load favicon it will show up all the time on sites like twitter or any Web 2.0 Web site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include "addthis" script in a separate function and call the function wherever you want. Also call the method using setTimeout. Eg:- setTimeout('AddthisMethod', 1000);

Comment: It will not work, because I have the same loading if I call $.getScript after an hour from console. (just in case it try it anyway).